# How to control display of iframe on a Sharepoint page?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a Sharepoint page created in a Sharepoint site based on Sharepoint 2013 Foundation. On the page there is a small area of iframe to display some content. Besides, on this Sharepoint page, there is a main menu bar at page top. Once the mouse cursor is placed over the main menu item, a pull down menu will be expanded automatically. However, it is found that the pull down menu is displayed behind the iFrame and this is not acceptable by users. What users require is the pull down menu should be visible over the iFrame.

May I know how I can achieve what users require? Thanks a lot for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the source to add CSS to the menu:

`z-index:-1`

Which will bring the menu over the iframe